# config.xml en phonegap no me funciona

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación android a través de `build.phonegap.com`
Tengo una carpeta llamada "miproyecto", colgando de ella están el `config.xml` y la carpeta `www` que a su vez contiene los html (incluyendo el `index.html`) y las carpetas img, css y js.

En el config.xml tengo las siguientes líneas:

```
<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

El caso es que phonegap me genera perfectamente el apk y luego me funciona bien el móvil, sin embargo, no me hace caso a la línea:

```
preference name="orientation" value="landscape"
```

y no me bloque la orientación, girando el móvil me cambia la misma. Y lo que quiero es que me salga en horizontal y no pueda cambiarse.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Se parece un poco a esto a mi parecer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462873/cordova-ios-landscape-orientation